# How to parallelize with jupyter and sklearn?

Tags: python, scikit-learn, jupyter-notebook, jupyter, ipython-parallel

I'm trying to parallelize the `GridSearchCV` of `scikit-learn`. It's running on a `jupyter (hub) notebook` environment. After some research I found this code:

```
from sklearn.externals.joblib import Parallel, parallel_backend, register_parallel_backend
from ipyparallel import Client
from ipyparallel.joblib import IPythonParallelBackend

c = Client(profile='myprofile')
print(c.ids)
bview = c.load_balanced_view()

register_parallel_backend('ipyparallel', lambda : IPythonParallelBackend(view=bview))

grid = GridSearchCV(pipeline, cv=3, n_jobs=4, param_grid=param_grid)

with parallel_backend('ipyparallel'):
    grid.fit(X_train, Y_train)
```

Note that I've set the `n_jobs` parameter to `4`, what is the number of machine's cpu cores. (It's what `nproc` returns)

But it doesn't seem to work: `ImportError: cannot import name 'register_parallel_backend'`, although I installed joblib with `conda install joblib` and also tried `pip install -U joblib`.

So, what's the best way to parallelize the `GridSearchCV` in this environment?

**UPDATE:**

Without `ipyparallel` and just setting the `n_jobs` parameter:

```
grid = GridSearchCV(pipeline, cv=3, n_jobs=4, param_grid=param_grid)
grid.fit(X_train, Y_train)
```

Result is the following warning message:

```
/opt/conda/lib/python3.5/site-  packages/sklearn/externals/joblib/parallel.py:540: UserWarning:

Multiprocessing-backed parallel loops cannot be nested, setting n_jobs=1
```

Seems like it ends up in sequential execution rather than parallel execution.

Comment: I think `n_jobs=-1` would lauch all the cpu core to parallel

Comment: @AlexanderYau: Just setting the parameter throws an error message, I've updated the post.

Comment: How many cpu cores in your machine?

Comment: @AlexanderYau Exactly 4 cpu cores.